# Xcode 4.4.1 & Core Plot: Apple LLVM compiler error when compiling Core Plot demo apps

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, core-plot, clang

I just have upgraded to Xcode 4.4.1 and get the following error message when trying to compile the demo apps included with Core Plot (`Plot_Gallery_iOS` and `CPTTestApp_iPad`):

```
clang: error: -Z-reserved-lib-stdc++: 'linker' input unused when '-c' is present
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1
```

However, I was able to compile and run the demo apps with Xcode 4.4.

Do I have to change some settings in Xcode?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grab the latest code from the repository. This has been fixed there.

The issue was with a series of older build settings. Look for the `OTHER_CPTLUSPLUSFLAGS` build setting in the core framework project and remove that (you're probably safe to remove the other obsolete build settings that appear at the bottom of the list in Xcode, too). In the Other C Flags list, I believe you also have to remove the `-lsdtc++` setting.

Again, these are fixed in the latest repository code, along with a few other issues, so you should probably grab that instead of the packaged 1.0 Zip file.

Comment: I downloaded the latest repository code and it works now. Thank you, Brad!

Comment: @AlexR - I hit the same thing myself a couple of days ago when I built against the 1.0 package instead of my newer repository copy. I think some of those older build settings might have been my fault, but Eric fixed them all a while ago. There just hasn't been a framework snapshot since then.

Comment: I downloaded the latest repository (1.0 it seems) and this didn't seem to fix it.  But potentially a different issue with coreplot in a newer xcode...?

Comment: @shim - The packaged 1.0 download is not the latest code from the repository. You have to manually check that out using Mercurial.

Comment: Oh.  How do you do that?   "hg clone https://code.google.com/p/core-plot/" ?

Alternatively, it seems to work with a static library install instead of dependent project -- what's the difference?

Answer (score 1):

Are you change the Xcode settings

1. Open your apps Target Build Settings, and for Other Linker Flags include this:

-ObjC

[core plot settings link](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/wiki/UsingCorePlotInApplications)

I think may be it is use full to you